# Forcibly sending an MQTT message before the window closes in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to send a last message upon window closing event in WPF, I'm Using M2Mqtt and `client` as the MqttClient defined earlier in my code with successful publishes to the same topic but for some reason this publish event never reaches the mqtt server, I need to send a last message to state that the current logged in user went offline, or if there is any better suggested way to achieve this, please help thanks!

Here is my code 'OnClosed" event:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       string Topic = "Intrinsic/chat01";
       string jsonData = @"{  
        'id':'Dian',  
        'status':'offline'
       }";
       client.Publish(Topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, true);
       client.Disconnect();
   }
   finally
   {
       base.OnClosed(e);
       App.Current.Shutdown();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The client may become offline for various reasons which are partly not interceptable (like a Blue Screen on the machine or a power outage).

I would suggest to use the MQTT mechanism „Last Will and Testament“ to execute code when a client goes offline. More information on this MQTT feature may be found here: https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-9-last-will-and-testament/

Comment: Thanks, just a curious question, doesn't the last will execute only when the `client` gets disconnected? or will there be like a session timed out if the window closes?

Comment: According to the link in the answer, the last will is executed for any case except regular disconnect. Regular disconnect should be interceptable separately.